# Python Pandas: Create DataFrame from dictionary that has values of list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have dictionary like below:

```
dict = {key_1:[[1, 2], [3, 4]], key_2:[[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
```

I want to convert this to a dataframe like below:

```
      colum_1 column_2 
key_1   1       2 
key_1   3       4 
key_2   1       2 
key_2   3       4
```

What is the most efficient way to do this. Thanks for help=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df = pd.DataFrame({k: zip(*v) for k,v in d.items()}, index=cols).T.explode(cols)
```

output:

```
      col1 col2
key_1    1    2
key_1    3    4
key_2    1    2
key_2    3    4
```

Answer (score 4):

Let us try comprehension to unnest the key-val pairs

```
pd.DataFrame((k, *l) for k, v in d.items() for l in v).set_index(0)
```

---

```
       1  2
0          
key_1  1  2
key_1  3  4
key_2  1  2
key_2  3  4
```

Comment: Nice one @Shubham ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### Using pandas methods

Here is a pure pandas way of doing this without using any list/dict comprehensions for anyone looking for this -

```
d = {"key_1":[[1, 2], [3, 4]], "key_2":[[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T.stack().droplevel(-1).apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

```
       0  1
key_1  1  2
key_1  3  4
key_2  1  2
key_2  3  4
```

---

#### Benchmarks -

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(d).T.stack().droplevel(-1).apply(pd.Series)
```

100 loops, best of 5: 2.56 ms per loop

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame((k, *l) for k, v in d.items() for l in v).set_index(0)
```

1000 loops, best of 5: 719 µs per loop

```
%%timeit
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
pd.DataFrame({k: zip(*v) for k,v in d.items()}, index=cols).T.explode(cols)
```

100 loops, best of 5: 6.53 ms per loop